# Apache Credential Caching with mod_authn_socache and Form Authenticator

Tags: java, apache, authentication, caching, proxy

I have Apache 2.4 running as a reverse proxy on my server, protecting a backend Tomcatserver (Confluence). People have to authenticate with a valid serial number of one of our products to be granted access to confluence content. I use mod_auth_form to show a custom inline login page and a custom external java provider to verify if the provided serial number is valid (for that, i use mod_auth_external).

This all works quite fine (not perfect, but fine). Problem is its slow as hell, because apache looks up credentials every single time a ressource is loaded, so if you navigate to another page, sometimes dozens of lookups are made. That way, delay is like 5-10 seconds. I've read that this is inevitable with basic authentication, but that you can cache credentials with mod_authn_socache.

Does anybody know how i can cache my credentials despite using form authentication and my custom provider? I've searched everything, but nothing matches to my configuration with form authentication and a custom provider (that just says true or false to a serial number). Does anybody know a different way to speed this up?

Thank you in advance for your effort!

(relevant part of my apache2.conf, in case you want to see it):

```
DefineExternalAuth authenticator pipe "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -Djava.ext.dirs=/etc/apache2/security/checkSerno/lib:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java/jre/lib/ext -cp /etc/apache2/security/checkSerno/config de.profiforms.checkSerno.CheckSerno /etc/apache2/security/checkSerno/config"

Listen 7171
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/login.php - [L]
RewriteRule ^/rs - [L]
RewriteRule ^/ /rs [R]

<Location /rs>
SetHandler form-login-handler
AuthType Form
AuthName "login"
AuthFormUsername "Iserial"
AuthFormPassword "Ipw"
ErrorDocument 401 /login.php
AuthFormProvider external
AuthExternal authenticator
require valid-user
AuthFormAuthoritative on
Session on
SessionCryptoPassphrase secret
SessionCookieName session path=/
ProxyPass "http://localhost:7170/rs"
ProxyPassReverse "http://localhost:7170/rs"
</Location>

<Location /login.php>
require all granted
</Location>

<Proxy *>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Proxy>
```

Comment: We are interested in a similar set up (mod_auth_form with mod_authnz_external).  Have you found an answer to your question?  Also, do you think it is possible to do some more logic in login.php (e.g. setting cookies)?  If you can share your login.php then that would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: in fact i have :) the best way is using mod_authn_socache (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_authn_socache.html). this is from 2.5 manual but were using 2.4 and it works. alternatively, there is also a user made module called mod_authenticache, we had it running and it works fine too, but its not as powerful as the build in one. unfortunately, i currently dont have access to our server with login.php, butyou can do whatever you want inside it (were using plenty of php and javascript logic in login.php). hope it helps